# Tried so many different models but cant get good accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, binary-data, synthetic-data

I am very new to the field of Machine Learning. My college seniors provided me a dataset to analyze and predict.

The data is purely synthetic, with 14 feature columns and a target column having values 0 and 1. The training dataset has 10k rows and is of 180kB. I have uploaded the training data [here](https://github.com/pj-mathematician/machine-learning-personal/blob/main/final_train.csv).

My first approach was to simply google and find ways to start. I found the website machinelearningmastery.com very easy to use. So my first model was trained by Neural Networks, using [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) tutorial. After trying out many different combinations, this configuration provided relatively best results:
3 layers : [26->13->1], epoch = 12, batch_size = 10

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(26,input_dim=15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_X,train_y,epochs=10,batch_size=10)
```

Spent a whole day just trying out different combinations in the parameters, and got a score of 0.62 AUC (The baseline is 0.630 AUC SCORE, my classmates have achieved scores of 0.66 even 0.68).

After searching alot on google, I found that machine learning models work better on purely numerical data like mine compared to deep learning networks. So I started exploring through different models. I used sklearn's LogisticRegression but it yielded the best accuracy of 0.59 AUC score, after trying out with many different parameters.

Then I found out about gradient boosting models. I tried implementing LGBM and XGBM, they yielded better results. After changing the parameters rigorously, I achieved an AUC score of 0.638 on the test set.

I tried some other projects like [tabnet](https://github.com/dreamquark-ai/tabnet) they are also yielding *decent* results, but not more than 0.64.

After exploring more, many sources suggested that I select specific features and/or transform existing features to improve accuracy. For that, I plotted correlation plots like these: [image: correlation plot 1]

[image: coreelation plot 2]

but I wasnt able to comprehend the information these plots are giving and I didnt get anywhere. For feature selection, I used sklearn's mutual_info_regression which gave this result:

[image: mutual]

and then tried sklearn's chi2, which yielded:
[image: chi2]

Then I tried the above mentioned methods with the selected features but in 1-2 cases the results got worse. There was no noticeable improvement in the accuracy.

I have spent 2 days on this, and still I havent got anywhere. I would be very grateful for a direction in which I can move forward with confidence and get better results.

Comment: Just a remark: You need to be careful to not overuse your test dataset. If you change and select your models based on the test dataset, the stated performance will tend to be too optimistic. The more decisions you take on the test dataset, the stronger that tendency.

Comment: @MichaelM I am using a 70-30 % split on my training dataset to test accuracy of my models, with every entry shuffled every time I try a new method. I dont have the target values of the test dataset, and the scoring is done by submitting my predictions on a link.

Comment: That does not change anything. It is called "overfitting on the test data."

Comment: This exercise typifies so much of what is wrong in data science education.  There are so many problems present here, e.g. (1) not using general principles to select a model development method, (2) not using a [sensitive accuracy score](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue), (3) playing with lots of methods to achieve a certain result, (4) not bringing any subject matter considerations into the formulation of the analysis plan.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Subject matter consideration does apply here, since `The data is purely synthetic`. It is rather an exercise to use a certain toolset (crossvalidation, model selection and training). - Other than that, you are right. Would you like to expand on how would approach the problem?

Comment: I would use a Bayesian logistic model (or penalized maximum likelihood estimation) that favors additive effects, applies slight shrinkage to nonlinear effects, and applies lots of shrinkage to two-way interaction effects.  I would judge model performance by a high-resolution calibration curve, logarithmic and quadratic (Brier) accuracy scores, and [this](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Initially split your data into 80% development data and 20% evaluation data. You shall only evaluate your model once.
2. Using the development data, use [k-fold cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) for training and evaluation of models.
3. Do not start with the most complicated model first (neural networks). Instead, always start with a variant of decision trees, because they are easy to train and often perform well. Specifically have a look at XGBoost and [RandomForest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forests-of-randomized-trees).
4. Either way, you will want to optimize your [hyper-parameters](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#).

Once you then have nice cross-validated results, you can use your model with the optimized hyper-parameters once to evaluate it. Everything else is [cheating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging) yourself.

Most importantly, best read a lot of sklearn documentation. It provides great insight not only into how to use their algorithms but also general insight on approaching and evaluating.

Comment: Data splitting is noisy and arbitrary unless the sample size is larger than 20,000.  100 repeats of 10-fold CV would be a good idea.